# Is there way to bulk paste more then 100 records in edit mode?

Tags: edit-form, copy-and-paste, bulk

I need to replace data in a few columns from my excel sheet into my sharepoint List.

I have 24000 records and want to bulk copy and paste....

I am only able to do 100 at a time, because when I do more then 100 I get a "Unable to communicate with server error"

Any thoughts or plugin suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Open your SharePoint list in a datasheet view (you can also edit from here), this opens your list in a datasheet with all the records from your list which will be easy for bulk updates and copies. Make sure your Web browser supports ActiveX controls.

Comment: I have it in edit mode where I can copy and paste, but it only allows me to copy 100 at a time even when it displays 200 records on each page, is there a way to do more then 100? This is what happens when i copy more then 100 records ...http://i61.tinypic.com/30c60rb.png

Comment: While being on the edit mode, modify view > under 'Item Limit' tab > Number of items to display:  100, select "Display items in batches of the specified size." and 'Ok'. Now you should be able to see all the records in the edit mode.

Comment: Yes I can view the records in edit mode, but how can I bulk paste more then 100 records at a time?.... Even though I am displaying 200 records, i am allowed to paste in do only 100 rows at a time.

Comment: If you are using SP 2013, there seems to be an issue similar to yours in the discussion here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/814d3330-9d0a-43d5-a38c-72bd28589da6/sharepoint-2013-datasheet-view-navigation-performance-issues-on-large-lists?forum=onlineservicessharepoint  The work around seems to be  -- creating a new Datasheet view for updating instead of 'DataSheet view' view format option. To create a new DataSheet view - select DataSheet view from the create view options. Also users have noticed that Chrome might be faster than IE with Datasheet views.

Comment: didnt seem to work, do you know how i would install a .wsp package in sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I found that when you change the fields to multiple lines of text, and increase the number of lines; then change to plaintext, then the list can be paste in.  I don't have as many individual rows, but I was able to past a few hundred lines.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/134802/43832)...

(Credit goes to [Miksteri](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/20707/mkstr))

> You can do it with PowerShell, from here you can see examples how to
> update list item values from csv file:

[http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25125.sharepoint-2013-powershell-to-copy-or-update-list-items-across-sharepoint-sites-and-farms.aspx](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25125.sharepoint-2013-powershell-to-copy-or-update-list-items-across-sharepoint-sites-and-farms.aspx)