# Can you bulk paste more then 100 records in edit mode?

Tags: copy-and-paste, bulk

I need to replace data in a few columns from my excel sheet into my SharePoint List.

I have 24000 records and want to bulk copy and paste....

I am only able to do 100 at a time, because when I do more then 100 I get a "Unable to communicate with server error"

Any thoughts or plugin suggestions would be much appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with PowerShell, from here you can see examples how to update list item values from csv file: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25125.sharepoint-2013-powershell-to-copy-or-update-list-items-across-sharepoint-sites-and-farms.aspx